# How to make sure that object is only visible inside sqare

Tags: c#

I'm moving the colored balls to down with a Double Animation, but they are visible outside the grey area. The area of the square should be the 'end' for the balls, even if they are moving far from it. Is it something in the animation or something in the grey area that I need to set / add in the grey object?

```
DoubleAnimation fall_in = new DoubleAnimation(-590, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)))
{
    AutoReverse = false,
    RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1)
};
```

NB: Using WPF via Visual Studio

[image: Not like this]

Comment: What UI stack are you using?

Comment: Are you asking how to mask to the grey rectangle or stop the edges of the balls from going past that boundary? Also is the WPF?

Comment: Assuming you are using WPF, you could try setting `ClipToBounds = true` on the containing box.

Comment: I'm using WPF indeed and the grey square is a Uniform grid
@JohnnyMopp ineed to prevent them to go past the boundary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@brian Rogers that did the trick!  setting `ClipToBounds = true`